# How to iterate over a matrix that may be one-dimensional in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Say you have a matrices like these:

```
a = [['a','b','c','d'],
     ['e','f','g','h']]

b = np.empty((0,4),int)
```

I want to take some rows (if they meet certain condition I check for in my real code) and stack them on b. I am doing something like:

```
for element in a:
   b = np.vstack((b, a))
```

But matrix a could be one-dimensional. Say:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d']
```

This may happen in my case because I am generating from a user written csv

Then, iterating over a would cause an error when I try to vstack, since each 'element' is 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd' and thus the dimensions being stacked do not match. It would be something like trying to do:

```
b = np.vstack(('a', a))
```

What is the best way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the basic operation is to operate on each 'row' of `a`, use `atleast_2d` to ensure `a` has 2d dimensions.  Internally it's code is simple, and worth studying.

Then rather than performing a `vstack` for each iteration, I recommend appending to a list, and doing just one stack.

```
def foo(a):
    a = np.atleast_2d(a)
    for row in a:
        # <do something to row>
        b.append(row)
    return np.vstack(b)
```

test:

```
In [45]: foo(np.ones((2,3)))
Out[45]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
In [46]: foo(np.ones((3)))
Out[46]: array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
In [47]: foo(np.ones((1,3)))
Out[47]: array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Appending to a list and then performing the array join or creation is common numpy practice.  The alternative is to define an empty array of the right destination size, and insert the new values.  That requires an iterating index.

---

The essence of `atleast_2d` in this case is:

```
if len(a.shape) == 1:
     a = a[newaxis,:]
```

It's a little more general, allowing me to use `foo(3)` and get back `array([[3]])`.

Comment: Thanks! np.atleast_2d is a helpful tool I was not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to iterate over the rows of your array to stack them onto `b`, as `vstack` alone will work fine. Consider:

```
a_1 = [['a','b','c','d'],
       ['e','f','g','h']]

a_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

b = np.empty((0,4),int)
```

Then

```
>>> np.vstack((b, a_1))
array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
       ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']], 
      dtype='<U21')
```

and

```
>>> np.vstack((b, a_2))
array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']], 
      dtype='<U21')
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I need to iterate over the matrix because in my real code I am checking some conditions for each element of each row, and if those conditions are met, I add the rows to the stack.